# JSon decode doesnt parse the response into a array

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl, server

I am trying to parse a JSON response from a server to a array, but it won't work.
I am using:
`json_decode($string,true);`

So that must not be the problem.

This is the code where I ask the server:

```
$curl_header = array();
$curl_header[] = "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode("$auth_code:");

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curl_header);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.kassacompleet.nl/v1/ideal/issuers/');

$result = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

// Handle and store result
$test = json_decode($result, true);

print_r($test);
```

This is the response i get from the server and after printing it:

`[ { "id": "INGBNL2A", "list_type": "Nederland", "name": "Issuer Simulation V3 - ING" }, { "id": "RABONL2U", "list_type": "Nederland", "name": "Issuer Simulation V3 - RABO" } ]1`

Also this strange nr 1 appears on the end of the string after i print it.

Does someone have any tips for me ?

Answer (score 1):

`$result` is probably `1` because this is what curl_exec is returning.  The HTTP response is being sent to PHP's output stream because you need to use the option `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to get the result back in a variable.

Try this:

```
$curl_header = array();
$curl_header[] = "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode("$auth_code:");

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $curl_header);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.kassacompleet.nl/v1/ideal/issuers/');

// need to add this option to have curl_exec return the response
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$result = curl_exec($curl); // result is now the response, before it was `true`

curl_close($curl);

// Handle and store result
$test = json_decode($result, true);

print_r($test);
```